# Solving $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{\ln{(3x+1)}}$

Tags: limits

How do I solve: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{\ln{(3x+1)}}$$

My attempt: set $3x = t$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{\frac{t}{3}}}{\ln{(t+1)}}$$

I can't get further though.

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hospital's Rule for this problem?

Comment: $$\frac{\sin x}{\log(3x+1)}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\left(\frac{\log(3x+1)}{3x}\right)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln{(ax+1)}}{x}=a$$

Comment: This is nice +1...but perhaps way too subtle. I'd add, perhaps, something like $\;\cfrac ab=\cfrac ax\cdot\cfrac xc\;$ or stuff.